# apache camel sql : request with like

Tags: java, sql, apache-camel, esb, blueprint-osgi

hello i'm stuck in this problem i have a query that take in setting the value of $ {body}

```
<to uri="sql:SELECT distinct substr(cust_account,4,3) as TypeCompte from bnaservice.customer_accounts where cust_account like '#${body[0]}%' order by cust_account?dataSource=moodleDB"/>
<to uri="bean:tn.ngtrend.CompteClientRest.Transformer?method=ToXml(Exchange)"/>
```

the value of $ {body} equal 001 but each time I execute the query it gives me a result null

I think the concatenation between $ {body} and% is wrong

is there anyone who can help me solve this problem,thanks

Comment: What happens if you remove the #?

Comment: the same problem, the result is null

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use a colon? Because `body` is like a named parameter.

```
like ':#${body[0]}%'
```

If this still does not work, I would try to concatenate the expression and the `%` in an Exchange property and then call the property in the SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get this working with this snippet:

(It's scala but it's practically the same)

```
transform("%" + _.in[String] + "%")
to("sql:SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE quote LIKE :#${body} ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
```